# How to label same value with specific user in R?

Tags: r

I have dataframe something like:

```
myData <-  "User App
            A   Wa
            A   Browsing
            A   Wa
            A   Browsing
            A   Ig
            A   Tel
            B   Youtube
            B   Ig
            B   Wa"

myData <- read.table(text = myData, header = TRUE)
```

To something like this:

```
> myData

  User App       Similiar
1  A   Wa           1
2  A   Browsing     1
3  A   Wa           1
4  A   Browsing     1
5  A   Ig           0
6  A   Tel          0
7  B   Youtube      0 
8  B   Ig           0
9  B   Wa           0
```

### Question

I want to label in **similiar** column. If the same user has the same app, it will be given label **1** or if there is no same app for that user, it will be given label **0**. For example, like user B, the apps in user B are all different so it will be labeled 0.

Any idea on how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(User, App) %>% mutate(c = n()) %>% 
mutate(Similar = case_when(c > 1 ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0)) %>% select(-c)
# A tibble: 9 x 3
# Groups:   User, App [7]
  User  App      Similar
  <chr> <chr>      <dbl>
1 A     Wa             1
2 A     Browsing       1
3 A     Wa             1
4 A     Browsing       1
5 A     Ig             0
6 A     Tel            0
7 B     Youtube        0
8 B     Ig             0
9 B     Wa             0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library (tidyverse)

myData %>% group_by(User, App) %>% 
mutate (Similar = ifelse(n()>1,1,0)) %>% ungroup ()
```

Comment: Anil, if there are more than 2 occurances of an app, your code may not give the output that the OP is expecting. For ex, if you replace 'Ig' with another 'Wa' in group A, count of 'Wa' is 3, your code will give Similar column value as 2 and not 1.

Answer (score 0):

An option with `base R` using `ave`

```
myData$Similar <- with(myData, +(ave(seq_along(User),
       User, App, FUN = length) > 1))
myData$Similar
#[1] 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

#### data

```
myData <- structure(list(User = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", 
"B"), App = c("Wa", "Browsing", "Wa", "Browsing", "Ig", "Tel", 
"Youtube", "Ig", "Wa")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using the `dplyr` and `data.table` packages. First we convert to a grouped table using the `User` and `App` variables. Then we use `mutate` from the `dplyr` package to add two new variables. First is `Similar_1` which uses `rowid` from the `data.table` package to apply unique row ids within each grouping. The second is `Similar` which uses an `ifelse` and `max` from `base r` to apply a 1 for groups with a max rowid value >1 and 0 for everything else. `Select` from the `dplyr` package is used to subset the data by removing the `Similar_1` variable.

**Code:**

```r
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

df <-  "User App
        A   Wa
        A   Browsing
        A   Wa
        A   Browsing
        A   Ig
        A   Tel
        B   Youtube
        B   Ig
        B   Wa"

df <- read.table(text = df, header = TRUE)


df %>% 
  group_by(User, App) %>% 
  mutate(
    Similar_1 = rowid(App),
    Similar = ifelse(max(Similar_1) > 1, 1, 0)
  ) %>% 
  select(-Similar_1)
```

**Output:**

```
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#> # Groups:   User, App [7]
#>   User  App      Similar
#>   <chr> <chr>      <dbl>
#> 1 A     Wa             1
#> 2 A     Browsing       1
#> 3 A     Wa             1
#> 4 A     Browsing       1
#> 5 A     Ig             0
#> 6 A     Tel            0
#> 7 B     Youtube        0
#> 8 B     Ig             0
#> 9 B     Wa             0
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**Original data:**

```
#>   User      App
#> 1    A       Wa
#> 2    A Browsing
#> 3    A       Wa
#> 4    A Browsing
#> 5    A       Ig
#> 6    A      Tel
#> 7    B  Youtube
#> 8    B       Ig
#> 9    B       Wa
```